# Duplicates in Golang code

Tags: go

How to get rid off duplicates from this code?

I thought about code generation with *go generate*, but I think will get the same result. On other side I thought 'bout use interface, but don't know how to apply(I know how to use them, but not in that particular case).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type First struct {
    X int
    Y float64
}

type Second struct {
    I float64
    J int
}

func ListFirsts(db map[string]map[int]interface{}) []First {
    ans := []First{}
    for _, v := range db["Firsts"] {
        ans = append(ans, v.(First))
    }
    return ans
}

func ListSeconds(db map[string]map[int]interface{}) []Second {
    ans := []Second{}
    for _, v := range db["Seconds"] {
        ans = append(ans, v.(Second))
    }
    return ans
}

func main() {
    db := map[string]map[int]interface{}{
        "Firsts": {
            1: First{1, 2},
            2: First{2, 3},
        },
        "Seconds": {
            1: Second{11.2, 2},
            2: Second{2, 3},
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(ListFirsts(db))
    fmt.Println(ListSeconds(db))
}
```

Comment: "Duplicates". Duplicate what? What are you expecting to be only one of a kind?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to achieve? You may be better able to organize the code, but there's not much here to de-duplicate.

Comment: I want to get function like ListAnything, i mean get rid of listfirsts and listseconds. Or get composition of code where i won't need remove duplication.

Comment: We can't tell from your example how you would use this, or how to remove duplications. You could do something like http://play.golang.org/p/rixBkEJO8v, but then you're just moving the code to somewhere else when you finally need to assert the types in the slice.

Comment: @JimB it's not a solution which i was looking for, but you gave me a good idea. Thx! You made my day!